# how to re patch a theme after new version using git

Tags: git, git-patch

I am using a theme for 3 years.
I have patched it a little for myself.

After dreamhost stopped php 5.6, I have to update to the new version.
I have already been using git from day 1.

Can you suggest how git help in re applying the same changes again on a new branch?

Comment: I suggest `git cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to figure out which commits you want to import. Than you can use `git cherry-pick <sha1>` or `git cherry-pick <sha1...sha2>` and the commits you wish to add to your new branch.

---

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one.

[image]

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)